# Would the phrase “No worries!” be understood outside Australia?

Tags: expressions, australian-english

In Australia, *No worries!* is a very common way of saying *You’re welcome*.

I wonder whether it is used this way in other English-speaking countries.

The phrase’s meaning can be understood easily enough in context, so it should therefore be safe to use, but I’m still curious whether it would sound natural to non-Australians.

Comment: The phrase is very familiar, but to me, it does sound particularly Australian. I almost find it difficult to say it in my own head without the typically Australian drawl that makes it ‘neaahhhrries’.

Comment: I'm Indian, and it'd be perfectly understood over here, too. It's not an uncommon way of saying "you're welcome" over here.

Comment: It's very common in the Western US.

Comment: I use that phrase quite a bit, mostly in writing (emails etc) as opposed to spoken. I usually say no problem when talking...don't know why, just feels more natural. I'm from the East Cost US.

Comment: Ten years ago it was a foreignism to me (AmE) first heard From BrE speakers, but now I hear it all the time in the US.

Comment: It is one of those things that tends to be heavily overused by the kind of people who use it. e.g. Person explains to a cashier that they have no small change only a £20 note. Cashier says 'No worries mate'. Why would anyone 'worry' about not having change? If someone gave me a £20 note for a 50p ticket, apologising they had no 50p coins, I would say 'That's alright you'll have 39 of them in a minute'.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What do you mean 'drawl'? 'Drawl' is defined (ODE) as 'to speak in a slow, lazy way with prolonged vowel sounds'. The example the ODE gives of where you would find such speech is Texas. Australians don't drawl. In fact when I lived 'down-under' I found it fairly easy to connect with Australians by first adopting a Cockney accent and then modifying it a bit, to make it more nasal. But Australian is founded on a South-East England accent, close to but not exactly London. It is certainly not a 'drawl'.

Comment: @WS2, I would certainly call the prolonged vowel in the Australian pronunciation of ‘no’ as a triphthong (or even tetraphthong sometimes) a drawl. I'm not saying Australian in general is a drawling accent necessarily, but in that phrase, it is.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I know what you mean about 'no'. But I would suggest that is just an Australian affectation with that particular word. Now I think about it, there are people in Britain who say 'no' similarly, especially when they express emphasis. As an East Anglian by birth and upbringing I feel especially close to Australian sounds (and even Australian values). The origin of the accent was identified by one indiv idual, whose name I have long forgotten, as Hertfordshire.

Comment: I've come across Japanese people learning English who didn't know it was an Australianism. BTW, there's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_worries) about the phrase!

Comment: Every single English-speaking person knows the phrase, and also knows it originated in Aus.

Comment: The phrase seems to have come to South Africa in 1986, with the movie Crocodile Dundee. It is understood to be Australian, but is fully recognised to mean "no problem", "you're welcome", "that's alright", or all of the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In England (and Britain generally, I think) it would be seen as definitely Australian. Not a bad thing, of course, but not 'natural' in your sense.

Comment: I'm in Britain and don't see this as particularly Australian.

Comment: I feel sure it is Australian in origin, seeming to typify a macho, big-guy, way of responding. It comes with a sub-textual observation that the person putting forth a request or apology is a cowering individual and is likely to be 'worried' about having to approach 'such an important person as me' in a state of apology. Probably goes back to the way those in authority addressed convicts.

Comment: When I was a kid in the '80s in the Midlands "no worries" was seen as a real Australianism - however in the past ten years or so, it's become a really common phrase to the point that its probably lost a lot of its Aussieness. That's kind of a shame! But then I use it all the time... how hypocritical...

Comment: "seeming to typify a macho, big-guy, way of responding" that's wrong, and it's surprising a "foreigner" would think that!

Answer (score 1):

That phrase is common here in New York City. It is a more relaxed way of saying *you’re welcome*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as prevalent as in Australia or New Zealand, but you do hear it in the US. I have certainly heard it in Texas.

Answer (score 1):

It is commonly used in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

I hear (and use) it frequently, but never to say, "you're welcome". As a matter of fact, used that way it would sound odd to me. To me it means what has happened isn't a problem or at least not a big one. "You don't have salmon? No worries, I'll take halibut." Alaskan here.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost stereotypically Australian. I do have the impression that it's slowly becoming more widespread, certainly in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly in Australia, *no worries* can be used to say *you’re welcome*, but that does not cover it's actual meaning.  I've read a lot of articles which say it is the same as *no problem* but it's not that either.
In all the usages I've heard, it basically says I understand or I appreciate what you are saying, but I don't want to respond with a formal phrase like you're welcome or all is forgiven or I am behind your revolutionary ideas and will follow you into the battle and die by your side.

BTW in Australia instead of *no problem* we would say *she'll be apples* or *she'll be right*.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know it was Australian... I live in New England and I hear some people say it, although it's used more like how "That's okay" or "It's fine" would be used, instead of as a "You're welcome" type of thing. I don't hear a lot of people say it though, but I know my voice teacher does, but she's from the New England Area, too, I believe.

Comment: Same usage here in the Midwest. I also didn't know it was Australian.